# Transformations of electroweak gauge field $W_\mu$ under $U(1)_{e.m.}$

Tags: standard-model, gauge-theory, symmetry-breaking, higgs, electroweak

As the vector boson field $W_\mu$ is, together with $Z^0$, the gauge field for the Standard electroweak model, I know it transforms as a connection under the $SU(2)\times U(1)_Y$ group. But, when this simmetry is broken to $U(1)_{e.m.}$, which is the transformation associated to $W_\mu$?

Comment: What do you mean? Having the gauge symmetry *broken* means that there are no real gauge transformations left.

Comment: Well,the gauge Group is broken, but not completely.there is a residual part,that is the elecromagnetic $U(1)$.then my question is: How does the fields defined in theory transform under this subgroup? Photon and leptons are quite straightforward,but what about $W\mu$?

Comment: The $\mathrm{U}(1)_{e.m.}$ trafo is simply specified by the electric charge, $\mathrm{U}(1)$ representations are boring 1D reps which are phase multiplications, after all.

Comment: So the $U(1)_{e.m.}$ mixes $W_\mu^+$ and $W_\mu^-$ fields as any other doublet? I wasn't very sure if the $U(1)e.m.$ as a residual of $SU(2)xU(1)$ break would behave so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the previous comments, I'm quite sure $W_\mu$ transforms with a phase-factor.
$$W_\mu \rightarrow e^{i\theta}W_\mu$$
therefore mixing the charged components of the $W$ field.